# Redrawing a UIView with a fade animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

In `TwUI`, there is a method called `redraw` on `TUIView`.  It forces the view to redraw, but it also comes with a free fading animation between the old and new state of the view.

I'm wondering if something like that is possible in a normal `UIView`. Basically, how can I redraw the view (`setNeedsDisplay`) with a fading animation between the old and the new states?

Comment: This question is similar, but not quite what I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730110/i-want-to-animate-in-fact-fade-within-drawrect

Comment: What do you need to be different from that other question?

Comment: That question only seems to answer fading in a view, not updating a view with a fade transition.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `+[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]` with the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` option, and inside the animation block, force the view's layer to redraw its contents immediately.

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
[UIView transitionWithView:myView duration:1
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
    animations:^{
        [myView.layer displayIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: You are the man! Worked perfectly.  I really should brush up on my Core Animation, shouldn't I?

Comment: Ha ha, maybe.  I learned a *lot* from the *[Core Animation Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#core-animation-essentials)* video from WWDC 2011.  But for your question I also had to write a little test program that changed the contents property of a code-created CALayer and see what animation it attached.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I'll watch it sometime.  I also bought the book *Core Animation* by Zarra & Long, but I'm ashamed to say I haven't read it yet.  Time to take a reading break! :)

Comment: You should **not** put animation code in the `drawRect:` method

Comment: @titaniumdecoy You are right, but I didn't know that when I originally answered. :)  I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a cross-dissolve UIView transition?

```
[UIView transitionWithView:aView 
                  duration:TIME_INTERVAL 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^{
                    // Change the view's state
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // Completion block
                }];
```